# Oracle 11 g release 2 sample schema

Tags: oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I installed Oracle 11g Release 2 on a windows 7 laptop and created a database using DBCA. In one screen there is an option to create sample schema but it was greyed out so I could not select it.

I searched the dbhome\demo\schema\human_resources directory but there is only one file in it -
hr_code.sql(It created triggers in hr schema). There is no sql to create hr schema or populate schema tables. I searched the net to download the scripts but no idea where to get them. Can you help me

Answer (score 1):

You can download the script from [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2719944/FULL-Script-Human-Resources-for-Oracle-Database).

Comment: Can you include the content of the link here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the ASP.Net Membership / Role / etc schema?  It's in `<oraclehome><11g>\ASP.NET\SQL`