# Example database schemas for different db types

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite, postgresql

I am looking for some adequately-complex sample database schemas that I could use for examples on my site http://sqlfiddle.com (my current examples are pretty pathetic).  I know about AdventureWorks and Northwind for SQL Server, but I haven't really heard of any other "classic" examples for the other database types I support: Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite.  Ultimately, I would like both interesting/familiar schemas and some cool queries as the "Example Fiddle" for each type.  However, for the moment I'm only looking for the schema; the queries can come later.  Please point me in the direction of some of those interesting schemas, targeted for each database type.

Comment: In case you're still looking, there's a sample HR schema that Oracle comes with. I mention that here ->  [Oracle 11 g release 2 sample schema](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6135393)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PostgreSQL see ["Sample Databases"](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Sample_Databases).

Comment: That's certainly a great start.  Thanks!